# Why is search not working in Laravel AMP?

Tags: search, amp-html

I am working on an AMP version of my home page - but the search is not working.
The AMP page is live
https://goldenpornlist.com/m
The action in the form is /search
The method is GET.

Somehow the route is not recognised by Laravel.

In the non-AMP, if you search for "test", it will land you at

https://goldenpornlist.com/search/test

while the AMP version lands at

https://goldenpornlist.com/search?term=test

Any idea pls?

Answer (score 0):

I had the searched term in the route but it works after I removed it.